# What is an optimal data structure for a dictionary that never changes after creation, does case-insensitive key lookups and supports "startswith"

Tags: dictionary, data-structures, tree, time-complexity

I need to build a dictionary that has these traits:

- Never changes after creation
- key lookups need to be case-insensitive
- supports a "starts with" key lookup where the searched-for string prefix will return a set of items associated with that fragment

A perfect hash map with a case-ignoring hash function would satisfy the first two, but would not satisfy the last requirement.

I was thinking just a simple tree where each node is the to-uppered char of the stored key, and finding a match would involve walking the tree, doing a binary search of a `to-uppered` char from the search string.

```
 +---+                    +---+
 | A |                    | B |
 |   |                    |   |
 +---+          +---------------------+
   |            |           |         |
 +---+        +---+       +---+     +---+
 | N |        | A |       | E |     | U |
 |   |        |   |       |   |     |   |
 +---+      +------+      +---+     +----+
   |        |      |        |            |
 +---+    +---+  +---+    +---+        +---+
 | D |    | D |  | C |    | D |        | G |
 +val|    +val|  |   |    +val|        +val|
 +---+    +---+  +---+    +---+        +---+
                     |
                   +---+
                   | K |
                   +val|
                   +---+
```

This seems like maybe a simplistic and naive solution.  Is there anything that would be better?

Comment: There are a number of variations on your approach: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: I would consider a trie for the "starts with," and if you want faster lookup by key, consider a minimal perfect hash.